# Couchbase java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException while getting multiple documents

Tags: java, couchbase

I am trying to get a document from Couchbase using the below code:

```
public synchronized  void initialize() {
  CouchbaseEnvironment env =
   DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment
   .builder()
   .connectTimeout(10000)
   .build();
  setBucket(proper
  .getCluster()
  .openBucket(proper.getBucket(),proper.getBucketPassword())
}
public JsonDocument findByDocumentId(String id) {
    try {
        return getBucket.get(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

I am able to retrieve 3 or 4 documents successfully, but then I receive a TimeoutException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:93)
 at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.get(CouchbaseBucket.java:100)
 at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.get(CouchbaseBucket.java:95)
```

Why am I getting a timeout and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the Key / Value operation timeout using the `kvTimeout(long)` parameter when configuring your environment.

EG

```
 CouchbaseEnvironment env =
   DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment
   .builder()
   .kvTimeout(5000) //in ms
   .build();
```

But I'd be concerned if you need to increase this and you're not stressing your system. This might point to poorly configured setup somewhere.

For a list of configurable options see http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/env-config.html

Answer (score -1):

Thread.sleep would help to avoid this issue.
We have to implement the wait time to next document read. This is not an solution but a work around.

Comment: I can't see how this can help anyone actually solve this issue.